# Menú dinámico mvc.sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, sitemap

Estoy realizando un sitio web MVC (.net C#) en el cuál contiene distintos Controladores, los cuales están asociados a diferentes roles. Estoy intentando realizar un menú dinámico respecto al usuario que ingresa al sitio.

**Ejemplo:**

```
Usuario1 
Roles asignados: Vista 1, Vista 2, Vista 3

Usuario 2
Roles asignados: Vista 3
```

**Vista de USUARIO1**
Vista 1
Vista 2
Vista 3

**Vista de USUARIO2**
Vista3

¿Cómo podría realizar esta tarea? que el menú se adapte al rol del usuario logeado.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La solución más sencilla es usar `User.IsInRole(string rol)`, de esta manera, comprobas si el usuario se encuentra en un rol específico y creas un menú para el, lo ideal, es trabajarlo lógicamente en alguno de los layout

Un pequeño ejemplo podría ser

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Detalle","Detalle")</li>
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Panel de Control", "ControlPanel")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Donde, si el usuario posee el rol `Admin` se va a visualizar el Panel de control.

Comment: A pesar de que se soluciona el problema, me temo que no es la opción más viable cuando se trata de tener muchos roles